# Changing CSS with PHP?

Tags: php, html, css

[Picture to get understanding of my question!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG5A4.jpg)

So, this is the site I made for fun and It's a little dice game where you can guess the outcome of the dice. **Anyways, as you can see there is a border under the other div. That's where the output comes from the dice game.**

[After rolling the dice.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19v7C.jpg)

So my question is:

**Is there a way to make the CSS style before doing the 'game' different than after playing the game?** (Border width: 0px; before and 1px after) **Or is there a better way to do this instead of changing the CSS??**

> *Edit by Martijn: The code given in the question makes to question obfuscated and didn't really need to be added. IMO it decreased the value of this question.*

Comment: Post your script, let's see how you are displaying those divs.

Comment: Alright, give me a sec :P

Comment: Or just don't output the DIV that contains the border styling, until after the submit button has been pressed?

Comment: Upvoted. This is a perfectly fine question, we're here to help people. He gave an example an is asking hwo to do so, so giving a code demo isn't an option (and really not needed anyway). Just because most of us think this is super easy, doesn't mean it is for a beginner.

Comment: Dankje martijn :P I updated the post with the scripts for the people who want to take a look at how I display the divs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Yes**, but first no: PHP can not change css. PHP is serverside, meaning it's build on a server and the result gets send to your browser. CSS styles the htmlpage on your computer, your computer´s browser calculates how big everything should be etc.

You can however, add a class to the html, depending on the result. This class can be styles.

You have not provided code, so´ll write you a small demo.

```
$indicationClass = ""; // not good or bad, so no class
    if( $Guess=="correct" ){ $indicationClass = "CorrectAnswer"; }
elseif( $Guess=="wrong" ){   $indicationClass = "WrongAnswer";   }


<div id="ImTheResultDisplayer" class="<?=$indicationClass;?>">
    The color of my text will change!
</div>
```

*This isn't perfect code, but it does demonstrate my point.*

If this is done via AJAX or Javascript (meaning the page never refreshes, you can use the same principle.

Comment: Thanks Martijn, I'll try it out. I also added the scripts now if you still need it.

Comment: I wanted to do it when It worked but I've been quite busy last days so had no time to try it. :)

Answer (score -1):

There is no way to modify your CSS with PHP

Try to learn Javascript add "movement" and other things to your web page, this language allows you to modify the style of your website after this is served by the server

Its a long way on web development but I wish you luck

Comment: You can improve your answer including an example of how to change CSS with javascript.

Comment: There is a way. After you POST you can decide what css to send to the user.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think learning 2 languages at the same time wouldn't really come in handy. :p Best of luck for you too :)

Comment: You should learn Javascript too, its a very important part of web development.
And its almost the same syntax of php